# Theorem 6.19 in Baby Rudin: Does this theorem hold for vector-valued functions too?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, proof-verification, definite-integrals

Here is the link to my earlier post here on Math SE on Theorem 6.19 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

[Theorem 6.19 in Baby Rudin: Do we need the continuity of $\varphi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359032/theorem-6-19-in-baby-rudin-do-we-need-the-continuity-of-varphi)

Can we extend this Theorem to vector-valued functions as follows?

> Suppose $\phi$ is a strictly increasing continuous function that maps an interval $[A, B]$ onto $[a, b]$. Suppose $\alpha$ is monotonically increasing on $[a, b]$, and suppose $\mathbf{f}$ is a mapping of $[a, b]$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $\mathbf{f} \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$. Define $\beta$ and $\mathbf{g}$ on $[ A , B ]$ by 
>   $$ \beta(y) = \alpha \left( \phi(y) \right), \qquad \mathbf{g}(y) = \mathbf{f} \left( \phi(y) \right). $$ 
>   Then $\mathbf{g} \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$ on $[A, B]$, and 
>   $$ \int_A^B \mathbf{g} \ \mathrm{d} \beta = \int_a^b \mathbf{f} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha. $$

Proof:

> Let $\mathbf{f} \colon= \left( f_1, \ldots, f_k \right)$, where each $f_j$ is a real function defined on $[a, b]$. Then $\mathbf{g} = \left( g_1, \ldots, g_k \right)$, where each $g_j$ is a mapping of $[A, B]$ into $\mathbb{R}^k$ defined by 
>   $$ g_j(y) \colon= f_j \left( \phi(y) \right). $$
>
> As $\mathbf{f} \in \mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$, so is each $f_j$. Therefore by Theorem 6.19 in Baby Rudin each $g_j \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$ on $[A, B]$, and 
>   $$ \int_A^B g_j \ \mathrm{d} \beta = \int_a^b f_j \ \mathscr{d} \alpha. $$
>   This implies that $\mathbf{g} \in \mathscr{R}(\beta)$ on $[A, B]$, and 
>   $$ 
> \begin{align}
> \int_A^B \mathbf{g} \ \mathrm{d} \beta 
> &= \left( \int_A^B g_1 \ \mathrm{d} \beta, \ldots, \int_A^B g_k \ \mathrm{d} \beta \right) \qquad \mbox{ [ by Definition 6.23 in Baby Rudin ] } \\
> &= \left( \int_a^b f_1 \ \mathrm{d} \alpha, \ldots, \int_a^b f_k \ \mathrm{d} \alpha \right) \\
> & \qquad \qquad \mbox{ [ by Theorem 6.19 in Baby Rudin applied to each coordinate ] } \\
> &= \int_a^b \mathbf{f} \ \mathrm{d} \alpha, \qquad \mbox{ [ again by Definition 6.23 in Baby Rudin ] }
> \end{align}
> $$
>   as required.

Is there any problem with this theorem?

Is there any problem with this proof thereof?

Comment: Sure. As the intregral is defined component-wise, this proof goes right through